# Get all letters before the optional colon

Tags: php, regex

I have a wrapper for PHPExcel, and I have a method called `setColumn()`, which looks like this:

```
public function setColumn($cell = ""){
    if(empty($cell)){
        $cell = $this->cell;
    }
    $this->column = strtoupper(preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z]/", "", $cell));
    $this->cell   = "{$this->column}{$this->row}";
    return $this;
}
```

It works just fine, but as I use it, I can pass in ranges such as `A1:D1` and when I do, my preg_replace will not replace correctly, it will return `AD` which I don't want. I want it to return `A`. I am not sure of the regular expression needed to accomplish this.

The parameter `$cell` can contain a few different values:

- `A1` should return `A`
- `A1:D10` should return `A`
- `AD10` should return `AD`
- `AD1:BBB1` should return `AD`

The list could go on, but that is the basics. So what can I do to acomplish that?

Answer (score 3):

Matches the digit than an optional colon then everything after that

```
preg_replace("/\d:?.*/", "", $cell);
```

Or as linepogl points out just

```
preg_replace("/\d.*/", "", $cell);
```

as long as the pattern stays: letter(s) number everythingelse

Comment: That could even be reduced to `/\d.*/`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
preg_replace("/^([A-Z]+).*$/", "$1", $cell)
```

It'll 'save' the first part and remove everything else.

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/fU1rO8).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with another solution, (Almost instantly after I submitted the question). What I did was explode on the `:` and used the first item in the array like this:

```
public function setColumn($cell = ""){
    if(empty($cell)){
        $cell = $this->cell;
    }
    $rng          = explode(":", $cell);
    $this->column = strtoupper(preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z]/", "", $rng[0]));
    $this->cell   = "{$this->column}{$this->row}";
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To explain what you are doing and what you want to be doing I've explained the regex below.

Your REGEX says to replace all characters that are NOT (indicated by the ^) in the array [A-Za-z] a capital letter or lower case letter. [Example](http://regexr.com?366pv)

What you want is to remove everything from where the first instance a number is parsed.
To match on a number use \d.
To match on any character use .
To match 0 or more of the preceeding token use *. This is a greedy match, and will match as many characters as possible before satisfying the next token.

If we combine .* this will match everything following.

To put it together /\d.*/ should accomplish this. [Solution](http://regexr.com?366q8)

Then

```
preg_replace("/\d.*/", "", $cell);
```